# How do I manage private packages that are intended to be used by multiple projects in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm only starting to learn about packages and in an attempt to modulize my app and break out parts I could potentially re-use for other apps down the line, I'd like to put some common functionalities within packages.

So with packages published in atmosphere i just type in meteor add  and that will give me the latest version of it.

However, I would not want these packages published on Atmosphere. Just wondering the best way to manage it?

Do I just create each of these packages in its own project folder and then just manually copy the contents to the packages folder of each app that utilises it? If so, how do I ensure the latest version is copied to each of the solution?

Is there a way I can use Meteor Add to point to a git repository or a private location instead of atmosphere?

Comment: OK wow didn't realize there was a question almost identical already asked. Happy to close this

Answer (score 1):

Meteor will search local packages into the directories defined by this environment variables: PACKAGE_DIRS .